# Can Intl.FormatNumber API switch automatically from standard notation to scientific notation like the standard API?

Tags: javascript, typescript, internationalization, ecmascript-intl

`number` values when converted to string use the scientific notation when greater than `10**21` (at least on my Chrome).

Is there an option in the `Intl.FormatNumber` API to also switch automatically?

Or is `10**21` defined in the spec and I can use this value as a condition for the `notation` property?